# Angularjs bind ng-model dynamically to an value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

i want change the reference for the ng-model value dynamically. i can do this for example like that:

```
$scope.test = {
  normalStringValue1 : [],
  normalStringValue2 : []
}

if($scope.status == 'A') {
  $scope.values= $scope.test.normalStringValue1;
} else {
  $scope.values= $scope.test.normalStringValue2;
}

<input ng-model="values" type="radio" name="xValues" ng-value="header.id | num">
```

this works but my problem is, the reference change did only work if the "normalStringValue1 or 2 is an array! if the normal string value looks like that:

```
$scope.test = {
  normalStringValue1 : null,
  normalStringValue2 : null
}
```

and i want only save a String like `normalStringValue1 : 'Hello'` the reference wil not change correctly why is that so ? and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$scope.test = {
  normalStringValue1 : '',
  normalStringValue2 : ''
}
```